# How do I send CSS file along with HTML file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to figure out a basic Node.js server. I want it to send my `index.html` and `styles.css` files when a client tries to connect to the "root" URL (what is the correct term btw?). Here's the code.

```
var http = require ('http');
var fs = require ('fs');

function send404response(response){
    response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type":"text/plain"});
    response.write("page not found");
    response.end();
}
function onRequest (request, response) {
    if(request.method == "GET" && request.url == '/'){
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/html"});
        fs.createReadStream("./index.html").pipe(response);

        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/css"}); 
        fs.createReadStream("./styles.css").pipe(response);


    }else{
        send404response(response);
    }
}
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888)

console.log('the server is running...');
```

The `styles.css` failes to load. Error on the client side: `GET http://localhost:8888/styles.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Why do you need to send the css file separately? Can you not add it as a `<link>` tag in the `index.html` file?

Comment: I did: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">` If I connect to`localhost:8888` It fails to load and apply. Only bare html loads. If I open the html file directly in file manager it works fine.

Comment: Remove the second `response.writeHead` and try changing `styles.css` in the `link` tag to `./styles.css`

Comment: Doesn't seem to change anything, unfortunately @Gaurav Punjabi

Comment: Can you check the Network tab in Chrome's Developer Tools? Is the CSS file request visible there?

Comment: I think it is. Here's an image of all of it to be sure https://i.imgur.com/sGDJiSE.png

Comment: It's getting a 404 error, which means the path is probably wrong. Can you show me your file structure?

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what the problem is. So you're sending every request to the function `onRequest`, even the link tag request goes there. Since the IF condition evaluates to false, it sends a 404 error as you have specified. Try using an express server and creating routes, or add another condition to check if the file exists at the path and if it does, then return that file as a response.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation that worked in my particular case I used the `swich` construct to handle different requests:

```
var http = require ('http');
var fs = require ('fs');

function send404response(response){
    response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type":"text/plain"});
    response.write("page not found");
    response.end();
}
function onRequest (request, response) {
    if(request.method == "GET"){

        console.log("request URL is: " + request.url);
        switch (request.url){
            case "/":
            response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/html"});
            fs.createReadStream("./index.html").pipe(response);
            break;
            case "/styles.css":
            response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/css"});
            fs.createReadStream("./styles.css").pipe(response);
            break;
        }
    }else{
        send404response(response);
    }
}
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888)

console.log('the server is running...');
```

Comment: This is not a good way to do it, if you need to add more files you will have to keep adding conditions. Try using an express server to serve static files from the directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
function onRequest (request, response) {
    if(request.method == "GET" && request.url == '/'){
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/html"});
        fs.createReadStream("./index.html").pipe(response);

        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/css"}); 
        fs.createReadStream("./styles.css").pipe(response);


    }else{
        send404response(response);
    }
}
```

In the above code snippet there is a problem with the `if` condition. You are only checking `/` url. When your html file tries to load the css, it makes a GET request to the server and the request url is `/cssFileName.css`. But in the above code you are not at all allowing the route. You are serving only `/` url and all other routes are giving `404` error as per your logic. So, you need to consider `/cssFileName.css` url as well to serve your css file. So ideally your code should be like this...

```
function onRequest (request, response) {
    if(request.method == "GET" && request.url == '/'){
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/html"});
        fs.createReadStream("./index.html").pipe(response);
    } else if (request.method == "GET" && request.url == '/cssFileName.css')
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/css"}); 
        fs.createReadStream("./styles.css").pipe(response);
    }else{
        send404response(response);
    }
}
```

But ideally for all the css and assets (images, videos), you should serve those from a static folder. So use `express` instead. For reference https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html